# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is Denied when Installing goose-extractor

Tags: python

I was trying to install goose-extractor using the tutorial on https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works.

But while I execute the command at my command prompt on windows 7 as this:

> virtualenv venv --python=C:\Python34

I got the Error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\Python34    
Traceback(most recent call last):    
File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main....    
.....    
.....    
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is Denied
```

My Windows user is Administrator.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you run the command line as administrator and then call the command?

Comment: Yes I did but the error remains.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have to provide not only the python installation directory, but point to the `python.exe` file. Following command worked on my 64 bit windows 8.1 machine:

`virualenv -p C:\Python2.7\python.exe`